# Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, java-8

I upgraded from Spring 3.2.3 + Hibernate 3.8.6 to Spring 4.1.6 + Hibernate 4.3 
now have the following error.
This is my springSecurityContext.xml:
  
Before that I run on Java 7.
I want to upgrade to Java 8, should I upgrade spring 4 and Hibernate
Help me. Thank

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1"
            default-target-url="/pages/" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_logout" logout-success-url="/"
            invalidate-session="true" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/pages/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/phantichtaichinh/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <session-management>
            <concurrency-control session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
        </session-management>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                <salt-source user-property="token" />
            </password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>mymessages</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.evnit.fmis.policy.model.PolicyManager">
        <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="com.evnit.fmis.policy.model.PasswordEncoderImpl">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="LoginLoggingPolicyService"
        class="com.evnit.fmis.policy.model.LoginLoggingPolicyService" scope="session">
        <beans:property name="guiLoginLoggingPolicService" ref="guiLoginLoggingPolicService" />
    </beans:bean>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="LoginLoggingAspect" ref="LoginLoggingPolicyService">
            <aop:pointcut id="authPointcut"
                expression="execution(public org.springframework.security.core.Authentication org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider.authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication))" />
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="authPointcut" method="loginLogging" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.htm" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
            ref="sas" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sas"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded"
                        value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

Description error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:14)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkLoginPageIsntProtected(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:191)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:36)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.afterPropertiesSet(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
    ... 29 more
2015-10-27 14:23:43,006 WARN   [localhost-startStop-1] XmlWebApplicationContext M[refresh] --> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in class path resource [springSecurityContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 23 more
2015-10-27 14:23:43,037 INFO   [localhost-startStop-1] RmiServiceExporter M[destroy] --> Unbinding RMI service 'TransferService' from registry at port '1199'
2015-10-27 14:23:43,037 INFO   [localhost-startStop-1] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean M[destroy] --> Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'fmis2'
2015-10-27 14:23:43,037 ERROR  [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader M[initWebApplicationContext] --> Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in class path resource [springSecurityContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 23 more
Oct 27, 2015 2:23:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in class path resource [springSecurityContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Change to  <br/><beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
  <beans:constructor-arg value="/session-expired.htm" />
 </beans:bean> <br/> Erorr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your configuration: one regarding `<http>` element and one regarding `ConcurrentSessionFilter`.

1. The class `ConcurrentSessionFilter` changed from [Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html) to [Spring 4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html). The constructor taking no parameter, [which was deprecated in Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html#ConcurrentSessionFilter%28%29), was removed in Spring 4.

   This explains the error you are getting:

   > Caused by: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()`

   which means that you referenced the no-arg constructor `<init>` but that it did not exist.

   You need to change your configuration to use the [two-args constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html#ConcurrentSessionFilter%28org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry,%20java.lang.String%29) instead:

   ```xml
   <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
       <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />
       <beans:constructor-arg value="/session-expired.htm" />
   </beans:bean>
   ```
2. Regarding to the `<http>` element, you have specified `use-expressions="true"` but you are not using Spring EL expressions. Quoting the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web):

   > To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to set the `use-expressions` attribute in the `<http>` element to `true`. Spring Security will then expect the `access` attributes of the `<intercept-url>` elements to contain Spring EL expressions.

   As such, you either need to set `use-expressions` to `false` explicitely ([the default value is `true`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-use-expressions)) or change your `access` attributes to `access="hasRole('...')`.

Comment: Thank you. I config start server success.
But when running the browser app notifications
The server is temporarily unable to serve.
Do you want to retry.
(403: Forbidden)

Comment: @user1550956 That sounds like a very different error. You should create another question about this.

Comment: I edit 
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            <beans:constructor-arg value="/session-expired.htm"/>
</beans:bean>