# Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'

Tags: spring, java-8, zk

I upgraded from Spring 3.2.3 + Hibernate 3.8.6 to Spring 4.1.6 + Hibernate 4.3 
now have the following error.
This is my springSecurityContext.xml:

Before that I run on Java 7. I want to upgrade to Java 8, should I upgrade spring 4 and Hibernate Help me. Thank

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd                        
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
        <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
            pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
        <http auto-config="true">
            <form-login login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1"
                default-target-url="/pages/" />
            <logout logout-url="/j_spring_logout" logout-success-url="/"
                invalidate-session="true" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/pages/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/phantichtaichinh/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
            <session-management>
                <concurrency-control max-sessions="2"
                    session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry" />
            </session-management>
        </http>
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
                    <salt-source user-property="token" />
                </password-encoder>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
        <beans:bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <beans:property name="basenames">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>mymessages</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.evnit.fmis.policy.model.PolicyManager">
            <beans:property name="userService" ref="userService" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
            class="com.evnit.fmis.policy.model.PasswordEncoderImpl">
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="LoginLoggingPolicyService"
            class="com.evnit.fmis.policy.model.LoginLoggingPolicyService" scope="session">
            <beans:property name="guiLoginLoggingPolicService" ref="guiLoginLoggingPolicService" />
        </beans:bean>
        <aop:config>
            <aop:aspect id="LoginLoggingAspect" ref="LoginLoggingPolicyService">
                <aop:pointcut id="authPointcut"
                    expression="execution(public org.springframework.security.core.Authentication org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider.authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication))" />
                <aop:around pointcut-ref="authPointcut" method="loginLogging" />
            </aop:aspect>
        </aop:config>
        <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            <beans:constructor-arg value="/session-expired.htm"/>
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
            <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
                ref="sas" />
            <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="sas"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
            <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
                ref="sessionRegistry" />
            <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="5" />
            <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
            class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl">
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:beans>
```

Description erorr

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:14)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
    ... 59 more
```

Comment: This is indeed an exact duplicate of your other question. You didn't apply properly my answer over there.

Comment: The suggestion to open a new question aimed at the problem you described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362315/33362840#comment54563939_33362840), i.e. “The server is temporarily unable to serve. Do you want to retry. (403: Forbidden)”. Your new question isn’t describing that different problem…